# Get minimum x and y from 2D numpy array of points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a numpy 2D array of points, aka 3D array with size of the 3rd dimension equals to 2, how do I get the minimum x and y coordinate over all points?

**Examples:**

**First:**

*I edited my original example, since it was wrong.*

```
data = np.array(
      [[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[11, 12],
        [13, 14],
        [15, 16]]])

minx = 0 # data[0][0][0]
miny = 1 # data[0][0][1]
```

*4 x 4 x 2:*

**Second:**

```
array([[[ 0, 77],
        [29, 12],
        [28, 71],
        [46, 17]],
       [[45, 76],
        [33, 82],
        [14, 17],
        [ 3, 18]],
       [[99, 40],
        [96,  3],
        [74, 60],
        [ 4, 57]],
       [[67, 57],
        [23, 81],
        [12, 12],
        [45, 98]]])

minx = 0 # data[0][0][0]
miny = 3 # data[2][1][1]
```

Is there an easy way to get now the minimum x and y coordinates of all points of the data? I played around with amin and different axis values, but nothing worked.

**Clarification:**

My array stores positions from different robots over time. First dimension is time, second is the index of an robot. The third dimension is then either x or y of a robots for a given time.

Since I want to draw their paths to pixels, I need to normalize my data, so that the points are as close as possible to the origin without getting negative. I thought that subtracting [minx,miny] from every point will do that for me.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: The comment behind the ???. Given a 2D matrix of points, return the x-and y-value which is lowest.

Comment: So... basically `data` consists of two 2D arrays, the first representing all the x coordinates and the second representing all the y coordinates, and you want to get the minimum from each? In that case I think your description is a little inconsistent: it would be the _last_ two coordinates, not the first two, that don't have any important meaning.

Comment: I clarified what I want.

Comment: @reindeer don't look that you did :) what output you expect if you replace 11, 12 with 13, 12? and please provide sample data with more points

Comment: I totally failed the first example, and edited it to match my question. Sorry for my brain lags.

Comment: @reindeer I updated my answer according to your comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you need consecutive min alongaxis. For your first example:

```
>>> np.min(np.min(data, axis=1), axis=0)
array([ 0, 1])
```

For the second:

```
>>> np.min(np.min(data, axis=1), axis=0)
array([0, 3])
```

The same expression can be stated (in numpy older than 1.7), as pointed out by @Jamie, s

```
>>> np.min(data, axis=(1, 0))
array([0, 3])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what the question is asking for. It wants the minimum value from each pair, and the fact that the result is the same as taking a slice is just coincidental.

Comment: Why do you use first time min and second time amin?

Comment: @reindeer just a legacy from your code; this is the same function (`np.amin is np.min` returs `True` for sure)

Comment: In numpy > 1.7 you can do `np.min(data, axis=(0, 1))` and spare yourself an intermediate array.

Comment: @Jaime just have thought about giving it a try (didn't yet ever), my initial guess was that this functionality would be rather implemented in pandas :) Can't test with exactly 1.7 (have 1.6 and 1.8 at hand), will it work in 1.7?

Comment: @alko Yes, multiple axes where added to reduction of ufuncs in 1.7, should have been >=.

Answer (score 8):

alko's answer didn't work for me, so here's what I did:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
x,y = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(array),array.shape)
```

Comment: Not sure that's what OP asked for, but it answered my question "How do I find the position of the minimum element in a 2D array?"!

Answer (score 1):

You should take the min of a slice of the array.
Assuming first coordinate is x and second is y

```
minx = min(a[:,0])
miny = min(a[:,1])

>>>a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

>>> a
array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6]])

>>> min(a[:,0])
1
>>> max(a[:,0])
5
>>> max(a[:,1])
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
minx = np.min(data[0])
miny = np.min(data[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function numpy.amin to find the minima along the desired axis.