# How to calculate the distance to a pixel

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image in numpy.ndarray. **The aim** is to calculate the distance from the **center** of image to a **darkest** pixel. Image shape = (717, 717), pixel range = (-0.812,  0.895).

P.s. It's a normalized cross-correlation output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the darkest means the minimum then you can get the corrdinate of the minimum with `x_min,y_min = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(array),array.shape)` (found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938586/get-minimum-x-and-y-from-2d-numpy-array-of-points))
then get the center coordinate with

```
x_c = array.shape[0] / 2 
y_c = array.shape[1] / 2
```

then you get the distance (in pixels) with

```
d = np.sqrt( (x_c-x_min)**2 + (y_c-y_min)**2 )
```